# PHP trying to use autoload function to find PDO class

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces, autoload

This has been bugging me for some time now and I can't seem to make sense of it.

My phpinfo reports that PDO is installed and I can connect to my database on my index.php file. But when I try to open a PDO connection on a namespaced class, php is trying to use my autoload function to find PDO.php which won't work.

My class is as follows:

```
abstract class {

    protected $DB;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {  
          $this->DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        }  
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is

```
Warning: require_once((...)/Model/PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /(...)/Autoloader.php

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/Model/PDO.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php') in /(...)/Autoloader.php
```

As far I as know the autoloader should be called because PHP PDO extension is installed (yes I'm completely sure).

My autoload is as follows:

```
spl_autoload_register('apiv2Autoload');

/**
 * Autoloader
 * 
 * @param string $classname name of class to load
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
function apiv2Autoload($classname)
{
    if (false !== strpos($classname, '.')) {
        // this was a filename, don't bother
        exit;
    }

    if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+Controller$/', $classname)) {
        include __DIR__ . '/../controllers/' . $classname . '.php';
        return true;
    } elseif (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+Mapper$/', $classname)) {
        include __DIR__ . '/../models/' . $classname . '.php';
        return true;
    } elseif (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+Model$/', $classname)) {
        include __DIR__ . '/../models/' . $classname . '.php';
        return true;
    } elseif (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+View$/', $classname)) {
        include __DIR__ . '/../views/' . $classname . '.php';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling `new PDO()` inside of a namespace, which makes the autoloader look for `\some\namespace\PDO` class?

Comment: $this->DB = new \PDO(...);

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not really an autoload issue. You are attempting to call a class on the root namespace.

By the looks of it, you are in some 'Model' namespace and calling `PDO`, you must remember that [namespaces are relative by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

What you want is to either call the the absolute path:

```
\PDO
```

or at the top of your file say you're going to use PDO like this:

```
use PDO;
```

Comment: Yes. That completely solved it. Went for the second form for consistency. Stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: +1: Perhaps the OP will be grateful enough to give you an upvote or possibly accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah... Can't upvote as I need 15+ reputation. But I am quite grateful :)